# lsof: show files open as read-write

Tags: lsof

When I try to remount a partition as `read-only`, I get an error `/foo is busy`. I can list all files open from `/foo` with

```
lsof /foo
```

but that does not show me whether files are open `read-only` or `read-write`. Is there any way to list only files which are open as `read-write` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To answer this question specifically, you could do:

```
lsof /foo | awk 'NR==1 || $4~/[0-9]+u/'
```

This will show files which are opened `read-write` under the mount point `foo`. However, likely you really want to do is list all files which are open for writing. This would include files a which opened `write-only` as well as those opened `read-write`. For this you would do:

```
lsof /foo | awk 'NR==1 || $4~/[0-9]+[uw]/'
```

These commands should work provided `FD` is the 4th field in the output and none of the other fields are blank. This is the case for me on Debian when I include a path in the `lsof` command, however if I don't it prints and extra `TID` field which is sometimes blank (and will confuse `awk`). Mileage may vary between distros or `lsof` versions.

Comment: Use `/[0-9]+[uw -]/` to include "mode unknown".

Answer (score 4):

Look at the `FD` column values in the output of `lsof`.  For example:

```
sudo lsof +d /foo
```

The manpages describe the interpretation; 'r' for read; 'w' for write' and 'u' for read and write access.

This can easily be used to list the objects of interest:

```
sudo lsof +d /foo | awk '/$4~/u/ {print $NF}'
```

Comment: I need a way to list all files open as `read-write` from `/foo`. The manual page `man lsof` does not mention this. Do you have a solution how to do it ?

Comment: This command gives me the following error: `awk: line 1: syntax error at or near {`. Also `+d` is the incorrect option for `lsof`. You could either remove this or use `+D` to walk every file under the mount point, although this will take a while.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have any luck using `lsof` to list processes with read-write access to files (maybe I just overlooked the option in my version of `lsof`), but I ended up finding [this Digital Ocean guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-linux-fuser-command) which showed how to get that info using `fuser`.

Here is some test output from an Ubuntu 16.04 box:

`$ sudo fuser -v /etc/os-release`

```
                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/usr/lib/os-release: root        827 f.... snapd
```

`$ sudo fuser -v /proc/kmsg`

```
                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/proc/kmsg:          syslog      989 f.... rsyslogd
```

As noted in the [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-linux-fuser-command):

> The above output shows that, when ran in verbose mode, the fuse
>   utility gives information about the USER, PID, ACCESS and COMMAND. There are many access types such as e(executable being
>   run), r(root directory), f(open file. f is omitted in default display
>   mode), F(open file for writing, F is omitted in default display mode)
>   and m (mmap’ed file or shared library).

In each of those above examples the files are open for reading. Here is an example of a file that is open for writing:

`$ sudo fuser -v /run/systemd/journal/syslog`

```
                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/run/systemd/journal/syslog:
                     root          1 F.... systemd
                     syslog      989 F.... rsyslogd
```

Here you can see that both `systemd` and `rsyslogd` have write access to the `/run/systemd/journal/syslog` "file" (socket in this case).